# Suitable places for super globals

Tags: php

I was searching where to use `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST`, `$_GET` but I only saw the differences among them.

The only I got to know that

1. `$_REQUEST` contains remaining two.
2. `$_GET` is used for fetching.
3. `$_POST` is used for inserting, updating, deleting.

I want to know these things

1. I want to know that when `$_REQUEST` can perform all the tasks then why there was need to create remaining two.
2. Explain the situations where we choose either `$_REQUEST` 
   and where we choose 
   `$_GET` or `$_POST` and not `$_REQUEST`

And what will the loss if we use use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET` or `$_POST`

Comment: `$_REQUEST` contains more than 2 things. How/where are you using these? This sounds kind of like an assignment, have you looked at the manual already? You could `inserting, updating, deleting` with `$_GET`. You could fetch with `$_POST`.

Comment: [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) is used to get the data in the URL's query string.  [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) gets data send via a POST request (with a `Content-type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`).  [`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) (by default) contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`.  PHP doesn't care what you are using the data from these arrays for, all they do is get data from the request.

Comment: It is good practice however to use the correct HTTP "verb" for the request you are making.  If you are fetching data, you should probably use `GET`.  If you are submitting (read "posting") data to be inserted/updated, then you should probably use `POST`.  See this: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: Thanks @Rocket Hazmat for providing useful link!

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't matter to you wether data comes in via post or via get you can use $_REQUEST. If you know which of the two will be the method data will be provided to your server-side code, use the appropriate super global. E.g. it's extremely easy to tamper with GET parameters, so you might want to avoid this method in certain parts of your application for security reasons. If you use POST you shouldn't read $_REQUEST, because there's a risk someone might add additional parameters in the URL via GET.